# C# Transparent Form using UpdateLayeredWindow draw controls

Tags: c#, winforms, png, transparent

I'm developing an exe where I need to have a transparent background. I have made the image in `Photoshop` and it has all the neat stuff (shadows/opacity, reflection etc).

I have been struggling to get it working using **TransparentColor+BackColor+Background Image**, but I always end up with some pixel not being transparent.  So I switched to **UpdateLayeredWindow** which works fine, but no control is being drawn now.

Here is some of my code

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateFormDisplay(this.BackgroundImage);
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateFormDisplay(this.BackgroundImage);

    }
    public void UpdateFormDisplay(Image backgroundImage)
    {
        IntPtr screenDc = API.GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
        IntPtr memDc = API.CreateCompatibleDC(screenDc);
        IntPtr hBitmap = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr oldBitmap = IntPtr.Zero;

        try
        {
            //Display-image
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(backgroundImage);
            hBitmap = bmp.GetHbitmap(Color.FromArgb(0));  //Set the fact that background is transparent
            oldBitmap = API.SelectObject(memDc, hBitmap);

            //Display-rectangle
            Size size = bmp.Size;
            Point pointSource = new Point(0, 0);
            Point topPos = new Point(this.Left, this.Top);

            //Set up blending options
            API.BLENDFUNCTION blend = new API.BLENDFUNCTION();
            blend.BlendOp = API.AC_SRC_OVER;
            blend.BlendFlags = 0;
            blend.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
            blend.AlphaFormat = API.AC_SRC_ALPHA;

            API.UpdateLayeredWindow(this.Handle, screenDc, ref topPos, ref size, memDc, ref pointSource, 0, ref blend, API.ULW_ALPHA);

            //Clean-up
            bmp.Dispose();
            API.ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, screenDc);
            if (hBitmap != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                API.SelectObject(memDc, oldBitmap);
                API.DeleteObject(hBitmap);
            }
            API.DeleteDC(memDc);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

Here are some images to explain better

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to call `base.OnPaint(e);` from within your overrided OnPaint.

Comment: Did you call it after or before UpdateFormDisplay?

Comment: I tried both none seem to work

Comment: size should be the unmanaged struct [SIZE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145106(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Changing the size struct wont change anything so I kindly ask you to stop posting useless comments which are in no way related to original question. Thank you

Comment: @user2920222 try placing the `UpdateFormDisplay` in the `OnPaintBackground` instead? BTW, you shouldn't try customizing `winforms` too much, if you want a better solution, try using `WPF`.

Comment: @KingKing seems like you have got the same mental illness as me. People are going to call you `troll`, `jerk` and the like, just for saying winforms is worthless and does not support anything.

Comment: @HighCore not really, I have to accept the truth that, customizing `winforms` is **possible** but it's too much work, as I said before, I just play with it **for fun**, in real project, we should use `WPF` or at least some kind of `hosted WPF control` in `winforms`.

Comment: Hey guys! We are going too deep, why dont we continue on the path of answering my question? Should i really use WPF? :(

Comment: @user2920222 as long as you program `Windows application`, `WPF` is what you should learn and use **sooner or later**. Your problem is a little complicated, to **free customize** winforms, we must have a deep knowledge about it, otherwise everything will be so messy, tough and look like **impossible**.

Comment: @user2920222 `Should i really use WPF?` - I'm not as forgiving as @KingKing, I say YES, you should really use WPF and forget dinosaur winforms forever. it's completely useless and doesn't support anything except forcing to you type a horrendous amount of unneeded code behind and looking like Windows 3.1. WPF supports MVVM which is a really beautiful and pleasant way to work, and you can customize as much as you want.

Comment: You cannot host controls in the window with UpdateLayeredWindow. They will not be displayed. Essentially you work with a bitmap. If you don't want to use WPF, there are tools for Winforms that allow you to create lightweight controls that will appear even on a transparent window. They are not true controls.

Comment: Downvoted because you don't show your API declaration.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use regular control inside layered window that uses `UpdateLayeredWindow` API, you need to override control's `OnPaint` method to redirect drawing to off-screen bitmap which you later use with `UpdateLayeredWindow` method to update window look.

If you don't want to dig into controls code, or don't have much custom made controls, `WM_PRINT` message could be used to force controls to paint themselves into provided device context. Classic window subclassing (`SetWindowLong`/`GetWindowLong`) for catching moments when controls invalidate themselves is useful, but may be slightly dangerous - you have to watch for callback chain.

Finally, you can use lightweight (windowless) controls. They use form message queue to receive events and draw themselves, so only form drawing code modifications are necessary. Some of standard winforms controls support this mode.